# For SEO, are clickable divs better than hashtag href anchors when the click triggers an in-page action?

Tags: seo, anchor

Let say you have a menu and when you click an element, the menu change to show something else (a menu part2 for example)

Is it better to use a classic `<a href='#'>` or a js clickable `<div>`? Or is that doesn't matter at all and I'm just overthinking?

Comment: What happens when you click the menu?  Does it go to a different page?  If so, I wouldn't use `#` in the anchor.

Comment: No, it stays on the same page. Just 2 containers moving